# How can I evenly space out the elements of my navigation bar using the width attribute?

Tags: html, css

Here's a simulation: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ9DP/

And here's the HTML and relevant CSS sections respectively:
HTML:

```
<div id="footer">        
        <div class="nav_wrapper">
            <ul id="list_orientation">
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
                <li id = "portfolio_text"><a href="http://www.google.com">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #heading{
    font-family:'ChunkFiveRomanRegular';
    position: absolute;
    font-size:80px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    text-align:center;
}

.border{
    border-top: 5px dashed #000000;
    border-bottom:5px dashed #000000;
    padding:20px;
}

body{
background:#ffdd22;
}

#subheading{
    font-family:'MuseoSlab500Regular';
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
}

.nav_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    /*width:30%;*/
    /*Change this
    width:30%;*/
}

.nav_wrapper ul li {display:inline; width:30%;}
.nav_wrapper ul li a {width:30%;}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:100;
}

#list_orientation {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:5%;
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LQ9DP/13/

Comment: Well, somewhat. I actually wanted the left-most and right-most elements to touch the ends. Also can you tell me why setting margin worked and width didn't work even though they were both supposed to clear space?

Comment: in case you give the fixed width the text inside the elements is bound to stay inside that space. And you can't be sure that all the text of your every elements will be same in size. In case of margin or padding no matter what is the size of the text there are always same spaces between them. If you want your first or last element stays in the edge instead of having a margin you can try `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo classes

Answer (score 2):

would you mind trying to give padding to the elements instead of giving a fixed width? And in case of centering the text vertically you may use the height of the text containing box same as the `line-height` of the text.